# How to train this neural network?

Tags: neural-networks

I seek the neural network (NN) which satisfies the 100 equations (i=1,2...100)

$\sum_{j=1}^{2000} NN(A_{ij},B_{ij},C_{ij})=Q_i$.

Where A,B,C are 100x2000 matrices

So I know Q, A, B and C
How can one find the NN? (ie train it using this data)
I have a second datset to test it on.
I also have MATLAB neural network toolbox, but that is not a necessity for me to use that.

Comment: Questions about specific software packages are off-topic here.

Comment: Is your neural network out of the ordinary? If so, can you explain in what way? Otherwise, you train the network just you train any other network.

Comment: But I dont have a target, I only have sums of targets.

Comment: I don't really understand your question – in your first equation, the network has a single parameter, and in the second, two parameters. Are you talking about two different situations? Also, it seems like you can find a linear function NN satisfying your constraints (if at all possible) by solving linear equations. So neural networks aren't really needed at all.

Comment: Two situations. This function is not linear.

Comment: Why not make it linear? Presumably you also want your network to classify some dataset correctly. Why not add your constraint to the objective function, in some soft way?

Comment: Ok, so in situation two, i can say NN(x,y)=ax+by+c ? Thats two variables and 100 equations.  What do you mean by linear?

Comment: It's up to you. You get to define NN in whatever way you want.

Comment: Ok you mean I can put the sum inside the function? Ok maybe that will work, i will try

Comment: That didnt work particularly well, probably because the function is not linear. Why did you think I could just impose it to be linear and get good results?

Comment: I suggested trying. You don't know the results until you try. Only after ruling it the "obvious" solutions, should we try looking for more sophisticated ones.

Comment: Ok it was a good idea. But whats next now ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $w$ denote the weights of the neural network.  Define the objective function $\Psi$ by

$$\Psi(w) = \sum_i \left(\left(\sum_j NN_w(A_{ij},B_{ij},C_{ij})\right) - Q_i\right)^2.$$

Then, find $w$ that minimizes $\Psi(w)$ using gradient descent.  You can find the gradient of $\Psi(w)$ using backpropagation through the neural network.  You can use all the standard methods for speeding up training of neural networks: stochastic gradient descent, Adam or momentum or Adagrad, etc.

This is very similar to training neural networks for regression problems.  The only difference here is that you are summing the output of the neural network on multiple inputs.  It is straightforward to adjust the objective function to take that into account, as shown above.